# Counting the number of files in a directory that contain the different variables in my array - bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, unix

I have a bash script, which needs to check certain files for certain variables, and count how many files come back containing those variables.

As there is more than one variable I need to look for I decided to to use an array for the variables.

The code I am using is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a MYARRAY=('Variable One' 'Variable Two' 'Variable Three');
COUNT_MYARRAY=$(find $DIRECTORY -mtime -1 -exec grep -ln $MYARRAY {} \; | wc -l)
```

I have declared the $DIRECTORY in my real script.
However, it does not seem to pick up files if they have the second and third variable within?

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: `$MYARRAY` - this is only the first element of the array. Does the variable names really contain spaces?

Comment: you can use `grep -s 'var1\|var2' *|wc -l` in the directory if you just want to have number of files containing these variables

Comment: @KamilCuk Hi, Yes the variables inside the array do contain spaces. The purpose of COUNT_MYARRAY is to count how many files are in the $DIRECTORY that contain either 'Variable One' 'Variable Two' or 'Variable Three' basically

Comment: If they do, then don't you get an error messages from `grep -ln $MYARRAY {}` ? Or the first element of the array just happens to now have a space.. You should at least see `grep: .: Is a directory`.

Comment: @Riz Hi, This command also works too, I just need it to pick up files created within 1 day which is why I used -mtime but working from just the command line this is good too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`s regex support and pass multiple expressions using `'var1\|var2'`. First construct the grep argument and then execute grep.

You don't need line numbers `-n` to `grep` to count the files...

`grep` can handle multiple files - it will be faster to pass multiple files to one `grep` with `-exec ... +`, rather then spawn `grep` for each file.

UPPER_CASE_VARIABLES are shouting at me and by convention upper vase variables are reserved for exported variables.

```
myarray=('Variable One' 'Variable Two' 'Variable Three')
arg=$(printf "%s\|" "${MYARRAY[@]}" | sed 's/\\|$//')
directory=.
count_myarray=$(find "$directory" -type f -mtime -1 -exec grep -l "$arg" {} + | wc -l)
```

Alternatively: you can pass multiple `-exec` arguments to find. So first from `myarray` construct arguments to `find` in the form `-exec grep -l <the var>`. Note that multiple variables can be in same files, so get unique filenames after grepping.

```
myarray=('Variable One' 'Variable Two' 'Variable Three');
findargs=()
for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}"; do
    findargs+=(-exec grep -l "$i" {} +)
done
directory=.
count_myarray=$(find "$directory" -type f -mtime -1 "${findargs[@]}" | sort -u | wc -l)
```

or similar:

```
count_myarray=$(printf '-exec\0grep\0-l\0%s\0{}\0+\0' "${myarray[@]}" | xargs -0 find "$directory" -type f -mtime -1 | sort -u | wc -l)
```

Remember to quote your variable expansions to protect against whitespaces or special characters in filenames and directory names.

Comment: I've implimented this into my script and it seems to work the way it is expected! Could you just explain the reason for using the for loop within it? just to get a better understanding?

Comment: Which loop exactly? You mean `for i in "${MYARRAY[@]}"; do`? I want to transform `( 'Variable One' 'Variable Two' 'Variable Three' )` array into `( -exec grep -l 'Variable One' + -exec grep -l 'Variable Two' + -exec grep -l 'Variable Three' + )`. I see there's is a typo, I meant, "you can pass multiple -exec arguments to __find__", not to printf...

Answer (score 1):

Going wrong:
With `echo $MYARRAY` you find `Variable One`, not the string you want for grep.
Also note that it is better to use lowercase for your variable names. I will use `${directory}` and not `$DIRECTORY` (and in double quotes for directories with a space).

You have more options with `grep`. When you want a file with 8 occurances counted one, you can not use the `grep` option `-c`. An useful option is `-r`. You are looking for something like

```
grep -Erl "Variable One|Variable Two|Variable Three" | wc -l
```

This is difficult when the variables might have special characters like `$`or `|`.
Another option of `grep` is using the option 
`-f FILE, Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line`

So you should make a function that writes the variables to a file, and use something like

```
grep -rlFf "myVariablesFile" "${directory}" | wc -l
```

When the content of the file is changing rapidly, you might want to avoid the temporary file with

```
grep -rlFf <(function_that_writes_variables_to_stdout) "${directory}"| wc -l
```

or directly

```
grep -rlFf <(printf "%s\n" "${var1}" "${var2}" "${var3}") "${directory}" | wc -l
```